# Translation question: 信じ歩けば?

Tags: verbs

> 誰の言葉を信じ歩けばいいの？

信じ comes from 信じる which means "to believe" and 歩 comes from 歩く, "to walk". Finally, 歩けば is a conditional meaning "if walk" so how is all this put together? What does 信じ歩けば means? What about いいの?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think 信じて歩けば is correct. The sentence need "て".

Comment: ever heard of the expression walk the walk and talk the talk?  hope that helps.  ~ば~いい is a construction you can find out more about in a grammar dictionary, and roughly means "if/when this is done ~ good result."  the suffix の can be used to ask a question informally.

Answer (score 5):

***In meaning***,

> 「[信]{しん}じ[歩]{ある}く」＝
>
> 「信じ、歩く」＝
>
> 「信じて歩く」
>
> ≒ 「信じて、（そして）[生]{い}きていく」

In other words, 「歩く」 does not necessarily mean "to walk" here.  It is used metaphorically to mean "***to live one's life (from here on)***".

> 「いいの」＝「いいのですか」＝「いいのでしょうか」

It is in a question form and in this case, the speaker is asking ***himself*** a question.

> 「Verb + ば + いい」 = "One should ~~", or more literally, "it would be good if one ~~ed".

To put it altogether:

> ***"Whose words should I trust to go on living (my life)?"***
>
> ***"Whose advice should I follow to go from here?"***

etc.

You would know the best because you are the one who has the context.  Pas moi!